# How to play animation/movie instead of iPhone splash screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, splash-screen

I want to play an animation(Gif) or a movie instead of Default.png. Is that possible? I tried what is described in this blog :http://www.cuppadev.co.uk/iphone/playing-animated-gifs-on-the-iphone/ but I don't know how to play a Gif animation instead of Default.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking about a sanctioned App Store app, then no, you can't use anything but a static Default.png.

If you're writing an app for jailbroken phone, this may be possible (but I don't know).

Comment: I am an iPhone developer and I want to play a Gif animation when my app starts. That's all I want to do

Comment: You could set the Default.png file to the first frame of your animation, and then kick off an animation on top of this once the app is ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

The Following code should come in 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
if(bundle != nil)
{
    NSString *videoPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"trail_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    if (moviePath)
    {
        videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    }
}

theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

theMovie.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
theMovie.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:theMovie.moviePlayer];

[theMovie.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
[theMovie.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[theMovie.moviePlayer play];
window.rootViewController = theMovie;
[self.window.rootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer.view];
```

In the moviePlayerDidFinish method load the screen which you desire to load.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to do it on the latest iPhone OS. A trick using symbolic link is currently blocked by OS.