# Movie after splash screen or splash screen as movie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there anyway I can play .mov, .gif or any formats after application launches? any suggestions will do :) or I can use animation in images the load it in 'application didFinishLaunching'. Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play animation/movie instead of iPhone splash screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474960/how-to-play-animation-movie-instead-of-iphone-splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

add this in your appDelegate.m file

```
  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     [viewController showSplash];

 }
```

add this in your view controller.m file

```
 -(void)showSplash
 {
     UIViewController *modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
     modalViewController.view = //here you use your video file
     [self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];

  }
 - (IBAction)hideSplash
  {
      [[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  }
```

Try this and inform us it will be helpful for you or not;

Answer (score 0):

Again, I just googled 'video splashscreen objective-c', and I found these :

[Add a video into splash screen or in the first view of the app (IOS xcode 4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972638/add-a-video-into-splash-screen-or-in-the-first-view-of-the-app-ios-xcode-4-0)

[How to play animation/movie instead of iPhone splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474960/how-to-play-animation-movie-instead-of-iphone-splash-screen)

[iPhone - Showing video as a splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575273/iphone-showing-video-as-a-splash-screen)

And I think you can find more about this topic, it is a really common one.

Comment: I've check your link. It seems to be that picture can only use.